# Matplotlib + PyQt not working in OX

Tags: python, qt, canvas, matplotlib, pyqt4

I'm developing a program (artview by the way) that uses PyQt4 and Matplotlib. One of our users however can't run it, I was able to isolate the problem in the follow script (that works in my Debian)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import matplotlib

matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')
matplotlib.rcParams['backend.qt4']='PyQt4'

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

# generate the plot
fig = Figure(figsize=(600,600), dpi=72, facecolor=(1,1,1), edgecolor=(0,0,0))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot([0,1])
# generate the canvas to display the plot
canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)

win = QtGui.QMainWindow()
# add the plot canvas to a window
win.setCentralWidget(canvas)

win.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

this gives the following error for him:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/tmp/testmp", line 24, in <module> win.setCentralWidget(canvas) TypeError: QMainWindow.setCentralWidget(QWidget): argument 1 has unexpected type ‘FigureCanvasQTAgg'
```

his configurations are

OX 10.10.5 with conda 3.16.0

Python 2.7.10 | Anaconda 2.3.0 (x86_64)

matplotlib 1.4.3

Qt 4.8.6

PyQt 4.11.3

I have look thought the internet, but have found no help. I want to know if anyone has any ideias why this is happening and if I should got forward and open an issue in Matplotlib's github.

Comment: That looks like you have imported multiple version of the pyqt bindings.  Do you have something else that could be importing pyside?  Try importing `QtCore` and `QtGui` from `matplotlib.qt_compat` (where we do a bunch of shimming to patch over pyqt4/pyside/pyqt5.

Comment: Thank you a lot, it worked, but it did because it loaded from PySide despite of `matplotlib.rcParams['backend.qt4']='PyQt4'`. Only the QT_API can force loading PyQt4. First do you have an ideia why is rcParams not working, second a possible solution for your software would be to load `QtCore` and `QtGui` from `matplotlib` to avoid this kind of problem in the future, but is this a good ideia?